# Capture a screen shot in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to capture a screenshot of a webpage using the mentioned below script:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\screenshot.jpg"));
```

I am getting an error as  "`The method copyFile(File, File) is undefined for the type FileUtils`". I have imported package import java.io.IOException; and import com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils;

Please help me on this!

Comment: @olyv Does not seen to be a duplicate. This is more a problem with `FileUtils` not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons IO is the library you probably want to use. Import `FileUtils` from `org.apache.commons.io`
([java docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), [home page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)).

Comment: The issue has resolved on adding the org.apache.commons.io (java docs, home page) package.